# How can you make a "playing in another room and it's raining" type sound?

Tags: sound, audacity, effect

How can you make a "playing in another room and it's raining" type sound given an mp3 and preferably with something like audacity or a free tool like that.

Something like this:

Answer (score 2):

Pan + Low Pass for Playing in another room.

For Rain using a sample of Raining might do.

You can use almost any DAW's Trial Version and do this. FL Studio Trial or even Ableton Live Lite.